# Ruby Watir Webdriver - How to identify and click on the element in div tag?

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir, watir-webdriver

**I tried to identity div element from a web page and click on it using watir **

**PAGE:**

```
<div class="account-buttons">
        <a href="/account/register" class="signup1 action-button">Sign Up with Email</a>
        <a href="/account/login" class="login1 action-button">Have an account? Log In</a>
          </div>
```

**Watir CODE:**

```
Then(/^I signup with email$/) do
  browser.button(text: "Sign Up with Email").wait_until_present.click
end

Then(/^I click on button with text "([^"]*)" in div identifier "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  browser.buttons(:text, arg1).divs(:class, arg2).click
end
```

**Exception:**

```
timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on #<Watir::Button: located: false; {:text=>"Sign Up with Email", :tag_name=>"button"}> (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
      ./Features/Step_definitions/ChefD.rb:73:in `/^I signup with email$/'
      features/Sanity_scenarios.feature:8:in `Then I signup with email'
```

Please help me how to handle this?

Comment: you can chat with the cucumber google group as to why, but 'universal steps' such as "Then(/^I click on button with text "([^"]*)" in div identifier "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|" are a cucumber smell.  The step is mired in specific implementation and does not well express what's going on.  strongly suggest getting and reading 'the cucumber book'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inside the link, div is the parent of that link,

So write this code

```
b.element(link: 'Sign Up with Email').click
```

Or

```
b.link(text: 'Sign Up with Email').click
```

It would work.

Comment: Welcome @VinothPandian